# Vue: Reuse loading spinner template and logic

Tags: vue.js

I've multiple (20+) pages where I need the following code:

```
<template>
    <template v-if="isLoading">
        <Spinner full size="medium" />
    </template>

    <template v-else>
        <p>Page data</p>
    </template>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            isLoading() {
                return this.$store.getters['loader/isLoading'];
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

I don't want to rewrite this part everytime I need it so is there a way to create something like a higher order component with access to the computed method and a way to add the hoc to the script tag of the different vue files? Or another way to archive this?

Comment: Just to be more precise and help you to find a better answer. How do you need to show spinner? On the whole page always or within each particular element that's doing async calls?

Comment: @The.Bear This loader is used for pages. But with a page I mean a `slot`. We are working with layout components. These can contain a shared sidebar and a slot to show another component where we do the async calls. In the future we will add other loaders or use local state for changes in child components (for example a search in paginated table data or charts)

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend extending the spinner component where you want to show the spinner. I've created a boilerplate setup that show a very simple implementation of this approach [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-lederberg-pbm0m?file=/src/components/spinner.vue).

The main idea is to expose a default slot for you spinner component, and wrap the page component in that slot.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <Spinner v-if="isLoading" full size="medium" />

        <!-- Slot for component data -->
        <slot v-else></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            isLoading() {
                return this.$store.getters['loader/isLoading'];
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Then in any component that you want to show the spinner:

```html
<template>
  <spinner>
    <!-- Pass here the component content to be shown after the spinner is hidden -->
  </spinner>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
  import Spinner from "./spinner";
  export default {
    name: "Page1",
    extends: Spinner,
    components: { Spinner }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. I've got a 'deep nested route' (multi router-views tags) that gets retriggered everytime.  The data is fetched in the component and not stored in the vuex store. When the spinner is removed and the page is shown, the data gets refetched and the spinner is displayed again. And so on.

I created a codesandbox with the rough structure of the project and implemented the spinner and pageloader [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-bush-7034v) Going to a detail page and clicking the `Rocket` page will lead to an infinite loop of refetches

Comment: You shouldn't wrap `router-view` in pageLoader. It destroys the component loaded from router every time it makes a request to the server. You should wrap only the actual component template. see the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-waterfall-y4y5r?file=/src/pages/launches/LaunchesDetails.vue).

Comment: Also, in `LaunchRocket` use v-if instead of v-show, because the later creates the component even if the rocket is null, and it is complaining about mismatched prop type.

Comment: Ok, check. But now `LaunchRocket` is rendered while `LaunchDetails` is fetching the basic data. If I go straight to the rocket page via the url, rocket will stay null because the `getRocketId` getter return undefined. In this example I could take the rocket_id from the url but in a big app It's possible that I need to wait for the data of the parent. So in short. How to show the loader while the parent is fetching data and afterwards fetch the necessary data in the child component before removing the loader. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't know if this is the best approach, but you could emit an event from PageLoader when the loading has finished (ie when all request triggered from parent finishes) and catch that event in child component to trigger subsequent requests in child. see my codesandbox.

Comment: I understand the approach but it leads to a double loader. I think this can be avoided. Since the start question is already a bit far from this new one, I will open a new question specific to this. Thanks for the help!